# How to make dynamic Image with states - react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

my function is:

```
  getImage(page){
    return
    (
      <Image
      style={{position:'absolute',height:'60%',width:'90%',padding:50,bottom:30 ,alignSelf: 'center' }}
      source={require('../../images/backgrounds/introduction/'+page.img)}
        />
    )
  }
```

---

```
render(){
return (
...
{this.getImage(activePage)}
)
}
```

but I got this error message:

```
Error: /Users/***/components/login/Introduction.js:85:14: calls to `require` expect exactly 1 string literal argument, but this was found: `require('../../images/backgrounds/introduction/' + page.img)`.
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of concatenation in `require()` you can use `state`.

Initialize one state say `imageArray={page1:require('link of page 1 image'),page2:require('link of page 2 image')}`

Then in `getImage()` use `Image` like this,

```
<Image
  style={{position:'absolute',height:'60%',width:'90%',padding:50,bottom:30 ,alignSelf: 'center' }}
  source={this.state.imageArray[page]}
    />
```

where `page` is the key from one of item of `imageArray` state.